# How I upload a project on GitHub?

Tags: git, github

When I execute `git init -b main` on the terminal, I face this problem:

```
error: unknown switch `b'.
```

How I fix it?

Comment: What is the output of `git --version`?

Comment: You might want to read https://www.biteinteractive.com/of-git-and-github-master-and-main/

Answer (score 0):

To initialize a new git repository after creating it on Github do the following:

```
git init
git add {yourFilesToAdd}
git commit -m "{your commit message} "
git branch -M main
#using ssh
git remote add origin git@github.com:yourUsername/repoName.git
#using https:
git remote add origin https://github.com/yourUsername/repoName.git
git push -u origin main
```

If you want to push an existing repository to a new one do the following:

```
#using ssh
git remote add origin git@github.com:yourUsername/repoName.git
#using https:
git remote add origin https://github.com/yourUsername/repoName.git
git branch -M main
git push -u origin main
```